# CSS Nth Child Hover

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create a hover over which changes from black and white to color but I cant seem to work out why i cant use a nth-child and a hover.

Currently my code looks like this.

```
<div class="ads125-wrap">
  <a class="ad125" href="#"><img alt="ad125" src="syteme-design-color.png"></a> 
  <a class="ad125" href="#"><img alt="ad125" src="syteme-design-bw.png"></a>
</div>


.ads125-wrap {
    height: 203px;
    position: relative;
}
.ad125 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: absolute;

}

.ads125-wrap a.ad125 img{
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out; 
}


.ads125-wrap a.ad125:nth-child(1) img:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need nth child in this?

Comment: maybe use first-child as first and then on second nth-child(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to target a **class** with `nth-child`and that does not work.

If all the links have the same class then this should be enough.

```
.ads125-wrap a:nth-child( add your number here) img:hover{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't get what you want at first place.
If u want get grayscale i recommend jQuery plugins such as:

**FIRST WAY:** http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/

(you can find many of them on web)
Second way is to use css filter (but you wont get support in every browser)

**SECOND WAY:** http://addcss.com/grayscale-to-color-hover-effect-using-css/

And the third way is to use css transitions:

**THIRD WAY:** http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

IN YOUR CASE IT IS:

**YOUR CASE:** [EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/lkqFt)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the class name of one of the images and let it sit behind the other image so only one image fades in and out?

http://jsfiddle.net/68Kb6/

```
<div class="ads125-wrap">
  <a class="ad125" href="#"><img alt="ad125" src="syteme-design-color.png"></a> 
  <a class="abcd" href="#"><img alt="abcd" src="syteme-design-bw.png"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot change the class names unfortunality

Comment: Then you have a problem